# How to write a forward hook function for nn.Transformer in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, hook

I have learnt that forward hook function has the form as `hook_fn(m,x,y)`. m refers to model, x refers to input and y refers to output. I want to write a forward hook function for `nn.Transformer`. 
However there are to input for transformer layer which is src and tgt. For example, `>>> out = transformer_model(src, tgt)`. So how can I differ these inputs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook will call your callback function with *tuple*s for `x` and `y`. As described in the documentation page of [`torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=forward%20hook#torch.nn.Module.register_forward_hook) (*it does quite explain the type of `x` and `y` though*).

> The input contains only the positional arguments given to the module.
> Keyword arguments won’t be passed to the hooks and only to the
> forward. [...].

```
model = nn.Transformer(nhead=16, num_encoder_layers=12)
src = torch.rand(10, 32, 512)
tgt = torch.rand(20, 32, 512)
```

Define your callback:

```
def hook(module, x, y):
    print(f'is tuple={isinstance(x, tuple)} - length={len(x)}')      
    src, tgt = x
  
    print(f'src: {src.shape}')
    print(f'tgt: {tgt.shape}')
```

Hook to your `nn.Module`:

```
>>> model.register_forward_hook(hook)
```

Do an inference:

```
>>> out = model(src, tgt)
is tuple=True - length=2
src: torch.Size([10, 32, 512])
tgt: torch.Size([20, 32, 512])
```

Comment: Love you, bro! I got it.